# C++14 can not call copy constructor or operator= of class inheriting from unique pointer

Tags: c++, c++14, copy-constructor, unique-ptr, move-constructor

I am having problems calling a constructor/operator. I have a class Tree which is a unique pointer to a Node. This is my code implementing the move and copy constructor/operator.

```
template <class Key, class Data>
class Node;

template <class Key, class Data>
class Tree : public unique_ptr<Node<Key, Data>>
{
using unique_ptr<Node<Key, Data>>::unique_ptr;
public:

/*Default empty constructor*/
Tree(){    
    this->reset();
}

/*Default constructor*/
Tree(const Key& key, const Data& data) : unique_ptr<Node<Key, Data>>(make_unique<Node<Key, Data>>(key, data)) {
}

/*Copy constructor*/
Tree(const unique_ptr<Node<Key, Data>>& tree) : unique_ptr<Node<Key, Data>>(nullptr){
    if(tree){
        this->reset(new Node<Key, Data>(*tree));
    }
}

/*Move constructor: roep de move constructor van unique_ptr op*/
Tree(unique_ptr<Node<Key, Data>>&& tree) : unique_ptr<Node<Key, Data >>(move(tree)) {
}

/*Copy operator*/
Tree<Key, Data>& operator=(const unique_ptr<Node<Key, Data>>& tree) {
    if (this != &tree) {
        this->reset(make_unique(Tree<Key, Data>(*tree)));
        if ((*this)->left != nullptr) {
            (*this)->left = tree->left;
        }
        if ((*this)->right != nullptr) {
            (*this)->right = tree->right;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

/*Move operator*/
Tree<Key, Data>& operator=(unique_ptr<Node<Key, Data >>&& tree) {
    if (this != &tree) {
        *this = unique_ptr<Key, Data>::operator=(std::move(tree));
    }
    return *this;
}}
```

when I try to copy Tree a to Tree b using the constructor or operator= I get an error telling me the operator is implicitly deleted. I know when you implement a move/copy constructor/operator the default ones can be no longer used and you have to implement all others too. But from my perspective I implemented all of these.

Code example

```
Tree<int, char> tree;
Tree<int, char> copy; 
copy = tree;
```

error: object of type 'Tree' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted

Comment: "*I have a class Tree which is a unique pointer to a Node*" - any particular reason why you simply don't use plain `std::unique_ptr<Node>` ? Your class inherits deleted copy constructor and copy assignment operator from **unique_ptr**. That is not going to work with what you want. Why would you ever want to copy `Tree` if it's a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Following the pre-written class headers from my assignment. Current task is to implement the move/copy constructor/operator. The goal was to implement a bottom-up version of red-black trees. A unique pointer marks the root of a (sub)tree, when using the rotate operation the owner/parent of the unique pointer changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "move constructor" and "copy assignment operator" do not have the correct signatures. They should be `Tree(Tree&&)` and `Tree& operator=(const Tree&)`.

When you do `copy = tree;`, none of your functions are used but the compiler generated default assignment operator is selected. And that happens to be deleted (`= delete;`) because the base class' copy assignment is deleted.

Comment: Although I tried this before without succes (because of another incorrect line further up the code), this was indeed the cause of my error. I appreciate your help!